# Is Azure App Service Free tire storage persisted

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage

According to price calculator Free tire App service gives 1 GB of storage.

What does this mean?

Can I store a json file and write/read to/from it?

Will it be persisted through out the lifetime of the service?

Can I get that file if I decide to shutdown the service?

Is there an alternative free/cheap storage in azure?

[image]

Comment: The 1 GB there is the space available in that virtual server instance.  Server instances and file storage are separate resources.  A server instance evaporates when terminated, file storage persists.  If you're familiar with Amazon it's EC2 instances vs. S3 storage.  Files: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/files/

Answer (score 1):

Thank you [Dave S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2287427/dave-s). Posting your comments as Answer to help other community members.

> According to price calculator Free tire App service gives 1 GB of
> storage. What does this mean?

The 1 GB there is the space available in the virtual server instance.
App Service complete pricing details can be referred [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/app-service/windows/) and the App service limits can be referred from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#app-service-limits)

> Can I store a json file and write/read to/from it?

Server instances and file storage are separate resources. If you want store a file and  write/read to/from it, you can utilize [Azure Storage Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-introduction).

> Will it be persisted through out the lifetime of the service?. Can I get that file if I decide to shutdown the service?

A server instance evaporates when terminated, file storage persists.

> Is there an alternative free/cheap storage in azure?

You can try [Azure Files](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/files/)